# How can I plot large (>1*10^7) values on a non-interupted linear scale in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, transformation

When I plot continuous data with large (>1*10^7) values the default scale is interrupted (see plot 2).

I know the scale problem is unrelated to negative and small (<1) values as I can reproduce the behavior with without them. I've included them in the example because solutions that involve transformations need to be amenable to negative and small values (<1).

Log transformations don't work well due to negative numbers and numbers less than one which switch signs after being log10 transformed.

I'd like to plot the data without any transformation if possible. However, the only solution I've found is to square root transform the absolute value data prior to plotting.

It's also worth mentioning that in my data set manually specifying limits or breaks would be challenging so I'm looking for a solution I can generalize to many plots when faceting.

Is there a way to prevent the scale issue without transforming the data?

If not, are there other clever transformation based solutions that may be more intuitive than a sqrt transformation?

Reproducible example below

```
x <- c("onefish","twofish","redfish","bluefish")
y <- c(-10000,0.001,10,100000) #values not so large as to induce problem
z <- c(-10000,0.001,10,10000000) #Last value large enough to cause plot scales to be interrupted

mockdf <- data.frame(x,y,z)

#Plot 1: No problem, linear scale for positive and negative values
ggplot(mockdf,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()

#Plot 2: Problem, interrupted scale
ggplot(mockdf,aes(x,z))+
  geom_point()

#Plot 3: Best solution I've found, continuous linear scale, preserves positives and negatives
mockdf$Sign <- ifelse(mockdf$z > 0, 1, -1)

ggplot(mockdf, aes(x, y=sqrt(abs(z))*Sign))+
  geom_point()
```

Comment: No. That plot #2 is not made with an "interrupted" y-scale. It's on a linear scale and the lower values are (perhaps) imperceptibly below, at or above 0. I'm getting the idea that what your really want to see  **IS** an interrupted scale.

Comment: Small comment: if you choose to transform your data in order to see differences between relatively close values, you may want to choose to transform the *scales* rather than the values themselves (as Jon Spring's good answer does). That way, the correct y-coordinate can correctly be inferred from the graph rather than relative positions of the original data. (I assume in this comment that the original data matter.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a nice place for my favorite transformation, `pseudo_log_trans`:

```
ggplot(mockdf,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.1),
                     breaks = c(-1*10^(0:20), 0, 10^(0:20)),
                     labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1),
                     minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Variation with more breaks. Note that only the breaks that are within range of the data (plus some margin) will be used, so you could expand them to far beyond the data to be safe for a wide range of possible values.

```
ggplot(mockdf,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.3),
                     breaks = c(-1*10^(0:20), -3*10^(0:20), 0, 
                                10^(0:20), 3*10^(0:20)),
                     labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1),
                     minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jon Spring! Is there a way I can generalize this solution so that I don't have to manually specify breaks when faceting many plots?

Comment: Only the breaks that are in range of the data (plus some margin) will show up, so you could specify a wide range (e.g. swap out `(0:15)` where I have `(0:7)`) and probably be set for most cases. You could also leave those out and see if you like the defaults.